# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE"

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I created a trigger, and this is the code below, for which I got the above error. I am doing this on Oracle Live SQL. I think it is a Live SQL specific error because the same code doesn't have much problems on a local database. Here is the code below:

```
create or replace trigger t1
after update or insert or delete
on emp_43
declare
o char(1);
begin
   if inserting then
           o := 'i';
   elsif updating then
          o := 'u';
   else
          o := 'd';
  end if;
insert into emp_trail values(o,sysdate);
end;
```

please help this noob out.
[this is the snapshot of the code and error on live sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnZFd.png)

Comment: I solved this, Snapshot of this code might show that I have put the sql query right after this PL SQL block. That isn't allowed. Thank you everyone. HEHE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct syntax is

```
create or replace trigger t1
  after update or insert or delete
  on emp_43
  declare o char(1);
  begin
  if (inserting) then
    o := 'i';
    elsif (updating) then
             o := 'u';
      else
             o := 'd';
     end if;
         insert into emp_trail values(o,sysdate);
     end;
```